# How can I import all the patents and patent applications on which I am listed as a co-inventor into my ORCID profile at once?

Tags: websites, bulk-download, resources

I am listed as a co-inventor on a few patents. [The Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lens) has an option to import a given patent from Lens into my [ORCID profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCID):

[image]

However one has to do it manually for each patent and patent application.

How can I import all the patents and patent applications on which I am listed as a co-inventor into my ORCID profile at once? I'm ok to use The Lens or some other service/program.

Comment: Is this a question about the format ORCID accepts for references ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite thanks, partly, more precisely it's about bulk import of patent refs into ORCID profile.

Comment: I’m not familiar with ORCID but I see the problem as knowing a format ORCID takes, the formats you can get out of specific patent databases and how to convert/bridge them. Can a CSV file be sucked in to ORCID and what fields do you need?

Comment: I've not tried this. You may need to create an account (free for non-profit use). This page describes the different features based on account type. https://www.lens.org/lens/accounts